# Do Chinese L Visas Require the Roundtrip Ticket Evidence to be to One's Country of Residence?

Tags: visas, china

I am going to be travelling in South Korea, and would like to visit China. However, I'm not quite sure of the dates that I will be flying to and from Seoul yet.

According to the Chinese Embassy, in order to apply for an L visa I need to provide (among other things):

> Documents showing the itinerary including air ticket booking record
>   (round trip)

I currently reside in London and would be getting the visa here. Could I just provide evidence of a round-trip ticket from Seoul to Beijing and back, or will they require me to provide copies of my tickets to Seoul from London and back as well?